# changing the background image of first cell of the table

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

I created a score board using table view and I want to highlight the first row of the table. When I run the app, the first row is highlighted as expected but when I scroll the table, several cell is highlighted instead of first cell.

Here is my code;

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "score", for: indexPath) as! ScoreTableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "firstClass")
    }
    cell.nicknameLabel.text = self.sortedResults[indexPath.row]["nickname"] as? String
    cell.scoreLabel.text = " \(indexPath.row + 1)"
        
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Use 2 different cell prototypes. One for row 0 with a backgrounImagzView and another without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells are dequeued meaning when your `cellForRow` is asked for cell ( that's not the first one ) the returned cell may dequeue that first cell so make sure to set `nil` when it's not index zero by replacing

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "firstClass")
}
```

with

```
cell.backgroundImageView.image = indexPath.row == 0 ?  UIImage(named: "firstClass") : nil
```

Comment: when I replace my code with your suggestion, only the first one is appearing and the others are not shown in the tableview

Comment: instead of `nil` set `UIImage(named: "otherClass")` if you have more than 2 rows keep an array of images or set a switch case inside `cellForRow` over `indexPath.row` to set appropriate image according to current index